# loop multiple key value pairs in python dict in single loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary where it has two key and value pairs such as

```
myDict = {'Key1':'Value1', 'Key2':'Valye2'}
```

I want to loop over key1 and key2 in a single loop so i can print the values of key1 and key2.

I'm able to do something like this, but this is printing the keys one by one I want print both keys in a single pass.

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    print(value)

# looking to print both keys values something like this.
for key, value in myDict.items():
        print(Value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `str.join()` function:

```
myDict = {'Key1':'Value1', 'Key2':'Valye2'}
print(' '.join(myDict.values()))
```

The output:

```
Value1 Valye2
```

---

If you definitely assured that your dict has only 2 items, you may do the following:

```
b,a = myDict.values()
print(a,b)   # Value1 Valye2
```

Comment: From this output would it be possible to save the values in variables? for example a = value1 and b = value2 ?

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for.